# How to share my folder being a non-administrator?

Tags: windows-xp

I don't have Administrator role on the present computer I am using in my office.

I want to share one folder to Public (to my colleagues). How can I do this?

I am using Windows XP OS.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have WinXP here, but I believe this should work even if you are not an admin (though it may depend on your user rights):

- create the folder "Public"
- click it with *right* mouse button
- choose "Properties"
- choose "Sharing"
- click "Share..." and specify the details

The details may depend on whether you are a domain user (in which case e.g. "Everyone" does not mean literally *everyone*, just all users from your domain), etc.

Comment: Hi Viliam, Thanks for your reply.
The problem is that I don't have permission to view "Permission" tab. I have to ask for the permission.